# What is the significance of the paintings present in the house of Dorian Gray?

Tags: penny-dreadful

In the series "Penny Dreadful" every time Dorian Gray's hall is shown it is full with paintings. So is there any significance to the paintings present?

[image]

Comment: I've not seen the series, so I won't answer - but the character comes from "The Picture of Dorian Gray", a novel by Oscar Wilde, where a particular portrait painting forms an important part of the story.

Comment: [Vanessa Ives: "They're all portraits. You have no landscapes or still lives." -- Dorian Gray: "Are not people the most mysterious things?"](http://penny-dreadful.wikia.com/wiki/Dorian_Gray)

Comment: @BCdotWEB Seems you are about to write an answer.

Comment: As I recall, he also has an abundance of portraits on the walls of his home in The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen.  I'd have to watch that again to see if it's discussed in that movie.

Answer (score 1):

The paintings in Dorian’s home represent all the people he has known and that hold a significant place in the span of his life, be it lover, friend or both. Remember how he photographed Brona and Miss. Ives? A remembrance he’ll have to accompany his immortality.